# Is it possible to use together pyggel and GLUT libraries

Tags: glut, pyopengl

I'm new to PyopenGL and i'm currently working on a code originally based on the pyggel library, but now I'd like to add some features from GLUT (menu & text) and I'm not really sure how I should join both (if possible).

In GLUT, running glutMainLoop() is required, but on the other hand I have this run() routine:

> def run(self):
>
> ```
>    while 1:
>        self.clock.tick(60)
>        self.getInput()
>        self.processInput()
>        pyggel.view.clear_screen()     
>        self.mouse_over_object = self.scene.render(self.camera)
>        pyggel.view.refresh_screen()
>        #glutMainLoop()
> ```

Putting the GLUT routine inside my run() doesn't work (it crashes when it gets to the glutMainLoop).
So, how can I join both loops? Can I? I'm guessing that's what I need to make both things work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely are not going to find this easy to do. Pyggel is based on the Pygame GUI framework, while GLUT is its own GUI framework.  You may be able to get text-rendering working, as under the covers GLUT is just doing regular OpenGL for that, but the menus are not going to easily work under Pyggel.

Pyggel has both text-rendering and a GUI framework that includes menus, frames, buttons, labels, etc. You likely want to use that if you're using Pyggel in your project there is an example of GUI usage here:

http://code.google.com/p/pyggel/source/browse/trunk/examples_and_tutorials/tut8-gui.py